# Open in a new tab not working as expected with s3 static website and cloudfront

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a couple of websites in my s3 + cloudfront, for example:

- www.example.com/test/#/
- www.example.com/test1/#/

www.example.com is the main bucket, test and test1 being the folders below and separate websites.

Now the problem is when I try to open something in a new tab, for example the dashboard. When is regular navigation the url becomes: www.example.com/test/#/dashboard and it works perfectly. But when is a new tab it removes the test, becoming: www.example.com/#/dashboard and giving me a 404.

Is this a angular configuration problem? Or cloudfront and s3 problem?

Edit, some of the routes config code below:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl:'test/javascripts/templates/welcome/views/welcome.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeController'
  })
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'test/javascripts/templates/dashboard/views/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController'
  })
```

Comment: It seems to be problem relating to angular `#` url's. Pls paste your routes and code to verify.

Comment: @Sravan Added the more relevant code from the routes file...

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be the issue with the `#URL's`

Add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to config file.

```
    app.config(["$stateProvider","$locationProvider", function($stateProvider,$locationProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl:'test/javascripts/templates/welcome/views/welcome.html',
            controller: 'WelcomeController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'test/javascripts/templates/dashboard/views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        })

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
    }]);
```

Now, you should tell the browser about the change, so you have to set `base href` in the HEAD tag.

**`<base href="/">`**

[CHeck this link for more information](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372)

Comment: I'm gonna upvote your answer because it helped me a bit, but I added the solution I found, Thanks anyway =)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel, np, the final thing which needed is to get the solution. Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Sravan answer remembered me of the base href tag in the index html, which I had set a long time ago. I had it like this:

```
<base href="/">
```

But since I am working with folders in s3, I think the / was pointing to the base of my url and removing the `test` from the url. So I just had to remove the / becoming:

```
<base href="">
```